# Proportion Confidence Interval

Tags: statistical-inference, binomial-distribution, confidence-interval

I understand this: There is a 95% chance any sample from a binomial distribution of samples of size n will have a sample proportion of success between:
$$p\pm 1.96*\sqrt{\frac{p(1-p)}{n}}$$

I don't understand why the 95% confidence interval for population proportion p is:

$$\hat{p}\pm 1.96*\sqrt{\frac{\hat{p}(1-\hat{p})}{n}}$$

can someone please provide a derivation of some sort, to me, it really makes no intuitive sense.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1448233/the-derivation-of-the-wald-interval.

Comment: Thanks! This helped a lot.