# Hypothesis test concerning a population proportion

Tags: hypothesis-testing, confidence-interval

The problem states that the national on-time arrival rate for flights in Nov 2018 is `79.66%` according to the Bureau of Transportation.
Suppose in Nov 2018, we observe `780` out of `1000` flights arrive on time in JFK.

I'm supposed to find a 95% confidence interval for the true population proportion $p$ of on-time flights.

First, I can calculate the $Z$ statistic using the formula

$$Z = \frac{\hat \theta - \theta_0}{\sigma_{\hat \theta}}$$, or 
$$Z = \frac{\hat p- p_0}{\sqrt{p_0(1-p_0)/n}}$$
where $\hat p = 0.7966$, $p=\frac{780}{1000}=0.78$, $n=1000$. I can just plug in an get $Z=1.27$

Now I can use that to get the confidence interval with 
$$\hat p \pm Z\sqrt{\frac{\hat p(1-\hat p)}{n}}$$

I don't understand where do I use the "$95\%$" here. Usually, I would also use that as a $Z$ value to for the confidence interval formula.

Also, I'm asked how can I give evidence that the actual on-time rate is different from the Bureau's statistics, without using hypothesis testing. Can I get help with this as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First question**: Confidence interval

You are dealing with a confidence interval for a binomila distribution. Based on the central limit theorem, you can state that:

\begin{equation}
\frac{\hat{p}-p}{\sqrt{\hat{p}(1-\hat{p})/n}}\sim N(0,1)
\end{equation}

And from this equation, you get that your confidence interval at a significance level $1-\alpha$ is

\begin{equation}
CI_{1-\alpha}(p)=(\hat{p}-z_{\alpha/2}\sqrt{\frac{\hat{p}(1-\hat{p})}{n}}, \hat{p}+z_{\alpha/2}\sqrt{\frac{\hat{p}(1-\hat{p})}{n}})
\end{equation}

Here your sample proportion here is $\hat{p}=0.78$.

Since you want your significance level to be $95\%$ then $\alpha/2=0.025$ and you need to find $z_{\alpha/2}$ such that $P(N(0,1)>z_{\alpha/2})=0.025$. In this case, $z_{\alpha/2}=1.96$

If you wanted a $90\%$ confidence interval then you would need to find $z_{\alpha/2}$ such that $P(N(0,1)>z_{\alpha/2})=0.05$

**Second question** Give an evidence that the actual on-time rate is different from the Bureau's statistics

You can solve this question by obtaining a confidence interval for the difference between the Bureaou proportion and your proportion.

**EDIT**: Expanded answer to the second question

Let us assume that $\hat{p_x}$ denotes your proportion 0.78 and $\hat{p_y}$ denotes the Bureau's  proportion 0.796. Let us also assume that $n_x$ denotes your sample size, which is $1000$, and $n_y$ would denote the sample size used for estimating the Bureau's proportion. I am not sure if the value of $n_y$ is given to you in the exercise. It should be given, but if not, I guess we can assume that the Bureau's sample size is also 1000.
In this case, it holds that:

\begin{equation}
Z=\frac{\hat{p_x}-\hat{p_y}}{\sqrt{\hat{p_0}(1-\hat{p_0})(\frac{1}{n_x}+\frac{1}{n_y})}}\sim_{H_0, {\ }approx} N(0,1)
\end{equation}
Where $\hat{p_0}$ is calculated as 
\begin{equation}
\hat{p_0}=\frac{n_x\hat{p_x}+n_y\hat{p_y}}{n_x+n_y}
\end{equation}

From here, 
\begin{equation}
CI_{1-\alpha}(p_x-p_y)=(\hat{p_x}-\hat{p_y})\pm z_{\alpha/2}\sqrt{\hat{p_0}(1-\hat{p_0})(\frac{1}{n_x}+\frac{1}{n_y})}
\end{equation}

This formula will give you the $1-\alpha$ confidence interval for the difference of proportion between your data and the Bureau's data. If the value $0$ is not inside the confidence interval, then then there is evidence that the actual on-time rate is different from the Bureau's

Comment: Actually, it is $\frac{\hat p-p}{\sqrt{p(1-p)/n}}$ which is approximately $N(0,1)$. It is while finding the confidence interval that we replace $p$ by $\hat p$, as is elaborated [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1448233/the-derivation-of-the-wald-interval).

Comment: So for part 2, I would use the $z$ value that I calculated as shown in my question for the confidence interval right?

Comment: And when you said 0 is not included, meaning the interval would go from negative to positive right?

Comment: @StubbornAtomwell you are right, but since the value of the population standard deviation is not known, we can approximate it using the sample standard deviation. I just skipped that step to make the answer more concise.

Comment: @PTN I have answered both questions on your comments in my edit.