# Why do we calculate margin of error by by multiplying z score and sample error?

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference

I understand the formula for the margin of error is z times standard deviation / square root n.

My question is why is this? I understand that the standard error is the number of standard deviations by which the value of a raw score (i.e., an observed value or data point) is above or below the mean value of what is being observed or measured. But why is this multiplied by the standard error (standard deviations divided by Square root n)?

Comment: It follows from construction of a certain confidence interval, since that is how it is defined at least on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Margin_of_error). Relevant: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_proportion_confidence_interval, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1448233/the-derivation-of-the-wald-interval.

Comment: @SubbornAtom is right about this having to do with confidence intervals. In order to give a coherent and specific explanation, it would be necessary to know the specific application. Presumably, you mean "margin of error" of a confidence interval for a parameter. What distribution, which parameter? A specific case might be CI for normal population mean $\mu$ when population SD $\sigma$ is known.