# Confidence interval without std?

Tags: probability, statistics

I have the following problem:

*A survey was done among 138 people. They had to choose between dark chocolate and milk chocolate. 88 of them preferred dark chocolate.
Compute the 90% confidence interval for the proportion p of the people who prefer dark chocolate.*

I know that the formula of a confidence interval is:

$[X+ Z\cdot\sqrt(\frac{\sigma^2}{n}), X+ Z\cdot\sqrt(\frac{\sigma^2}{n})]$

With X = 88/138 and n = 138. But I am stuck because the standard deviation is not given. I know that the survey is done only once, does that mean that there is no std?

How do I proceed?

Thanks

Comment: @PeterForeman: side question: is this an unbiaised estimator of the variance ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust I believe so because any function of an unbiased estimator provides an unbiased estimator.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_proportion_confidence_interval, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1448233/321264.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The confidence interval for the proportion is

$[p-z \sqrt{\frac{p(1-p)}{n}}, p+z \sqrt{\frac{p(1-p)}{n}}]$

Where $p$ is the sample proportion.

Comment: What is $z$ here ?

Comment: It is the quantile of the normal distribution and it is given according to confidence level.

Comment: thank you for pointing this out!

Answer (score 2):

The distribution is a binomial law with estimated probability $p=\frac{88}{138}$. The confidence interval can be obtained as the $5\%$ and $95\%$ quantiles of the binomial distribution $B(n,p)$.

The Gaussian approximation is justified, though the upper limits differs by one unit (low limit in $[78,79]$, high limit in $[96,97]$ or $[97,98]$).

[image]